# Kafka Connect to persist topic to Elasticsearch index using field from (json) message

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm attempting to index messages in Elasticsearch using SMT's from Kafka's Connect API only.

So far I had luck with simply using the topic and timestamp router functionality.
However, now I'd like to create separate indices based on a certain field in the message.

Suppose the messages are formatted as such:

```
{"productId": 1, "category": "boat", "price": 135000}
{"productId": 1, "category": "helicopter", "price": 300000}
{"productId": 1, "category": "car", "price": 25000}
```

Would it somehow be possible to index these to the following indices based on product category?

- product-boat
- product-helicopter
- product-car

or would I have to create separate topics for every single category (knowing that it could become hundreds or thousands of them)?

Am I overseeing a transform that could do this or is this simply not possible and will a custom component have to be built?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Confluent Platform` you can do some kind of routing depends on field value in the message.

To do that you have to use `ExtractTopic` SMT from Confluent. More details regarding that SMT can be found at https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/extracttopic.html#extracttopic

Kafka Sink Connector processes messages, that are represented by `SinkRecord`. Each `SinkRecord` contains of several fields: `topic`, `partition`, `value`, `key`, etc. Those fields are set by Kafka Connect and using transformation you can change those value. `ExtractTopic` SMT changes value of `topic` based on `value` or `key` of the message.

Transformations configuration will be something like that:

```js
{
...
    "transforms": "ExtractTopic",
    "transforms.ExtractTopic.type": "io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Value",
    "transforms.ExtractTopic.field": "name",  <-- name of field, that value will be used as index name
...
}
```

**One limitation** is, that you have to create indices in advance.

How I assume you are using [Elasticsearch Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html). Elasticsearch connector has ability to create index, but it does it when its *opens* - method to create writers for particular partition (`ElasticsearchSinkTask::open`). In your use case at that moment all indices can't be created, because value of all messages are not available.

Maybe it isn't the purest approach, because `ExtractTopic` should be rather used for Source connectors, but in you case it might work.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing out of the box with Kafka Connect that will do this. You have a few options:

1. The Elasticsearch sink connector will route messages to a target index based on its topic, so you could write a custom SMT that would inspect a message and route it to a different topic accordingly
2. Use a stream processor to pre-process the messages such that they're already on different topics by the time they are consumed by the Elasticsearch sink connector. For example, Kafka Streams or KSQL.

   - KSQL you would need to hard code each category (`CREATE STREAM product-boat AS SELECT * FROM messages WHERE category='boat'` etc)
   - Kafka Streams now has Dynamic Routing ([KIP-303](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-303%3A+Add+Dynamic+Routing+in+Streams+Sink)) which would be a more flexible way of doing it
3. Handcode a bespoke Elasticsearch sink connector with the logic coded in to route the messages to indices based on message contents. This feels like the worst of the three approach IMO.